# scrollTop jQuery, scrolling to div with id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, position

So this is the current code I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.abouta').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:308}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('.portfolioa').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:708}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('.contacta').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1108}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

When you click a link e.g. 'abouta' it scrolls to that specific section of the page. I'd rather do a `scrollTo` and then the id of a div so that I don't have to keep changing the `scrollTo` position if I change padding etc. Is there any way?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

instead of

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:xxx}, 'slow');
```

use

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#div_id').position().top}, 'slow');
```

this will return the absolute top position of whatever element you select as `#div_id`

Comment: I am surprised no one has commented in so long - the question as it stands, really asks for `.offset()` rather than `.position()` as a solution, right? The target div could be anywhere on the page, and `.position()` [returns the top offset relative to its container box](http://api.jquery.com/position/). So the above code will take you to the top of your document, if the target div is a first child of its parent. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Sameers, thats exactly the issue I was having. .offset() works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was the following:

```
document.getElementById("agent_details").scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I needed this to scroll top to a particular row of a html table. this works with the row id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#xxx').position().top}, 'slow');
$('#xxx').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $('#div_id').animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('html').animate({ scrollTop: $("#yourDiv").offset().top-100 }, "slow");
```

Answer (score -2):

if you want to scroll just only some div, can use the div id instead of 'html, body'

```
$('html, body').animate(...
```

use

```
$('#mydivid').animate(...
```

Comment: Nope, `$('#div').animate({scrollTop:$('#div').position().top}, 'slow');` doesn't work. (Chrome 23). Better use `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#div_id').position().top}, 'slow');`